# Pyplot plt.pause() delay gets longer everytime it runs

Tags: python, matplotlib, pause

im trying to make a program that plots points, shows the plt, and pauses for 0.1 sec. Now everytime i run the program the plt.pause(0.1) function seems to be additive. Anyone have a clue how to fix that? I timed it using the code below but you can feel the time-gaps between runs get longer.

```
        start = time.process_time()
        plt.show(block=False)
        print("2: ", time.process_time() - start)
        start = time.process_time()
        plt.pause(0.1)
        print("3: ", time.process_time() - start)
```

Output in terminal
(First time it run and last time before closing it)

```
2:  0.0
3:  1.328125

2:  0.0
3:  4.703125
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Matplotlib does not necessarily draw a figure canvas the moment you call `plt.show()`. IIRC, with `block=False` the figure canvas is not actually drawn until the first `plt.pause` command (or when control is returned to the user at the end of script execution). So nothing actually happens at the `plt.show` call, which is hence fast. The first `plt.pause` call is slow, as that is the point in the script when the figure is actually drawn. If you add another `plt.pause` call, the execution time is short again.

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

start = time.process_time()
plt.show(block=False)
print("2: ", time.process_time() - start)

start = time.process_time()
plt.pause(0.1)
print("3: ", time.process_time() - start)

start = time.process_time()
plt.pause(0.1)
print("4: ", time.process_time() - start)

# 2:  0.00012074099999992427
# 3:  0.020836499999999925
# 4:  0.007637112999999918
```